# How to add crosstab correctly for the json source?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to apply a rowspan for a table using crosstab. I need a table/crosstab to look like:
[image]

I have a json look like:

```
"indicatorSummaries": [
      {
        "indicatorCode": "IMPORTS_SUSPICIOUS_API",
        "indicatorScore": 15,
        "count": 1,
        "tags": [
            "priv/qwe123",
          "priv/qwe233323"
            ]
      },
      {
        "indicatorCode": "OPEN_SERVICE_AB",
        "indicatorScore": 50,
        "count": 1,
        "tags": ["tag11"]
      }
    ]
```

Is the JSON wrong for crosstab data source? Or which values should I use for **columns**, **rows**, **measures** to make it look like this? The dataset is configured right. A simple table works fine, but when I try to add a crosstab, it doesn't appear in the preview...